# Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/sass/app.scss

Tags: forms, authentication, manifest, vite, laravel-9

I have installed laravel 9 and livewire. When i try to open login or registraration page from top corner it's showing this error [image]

Can you tell me something how can i fix this one

Comment: Are you using one of any of the pre-built auth scaffolding?

Comment: Run ```npm run dev```

Answer (score 13):

For me was:
When i used in view

```
@vite(['resources/scss/style.scss'])
```

I had to add in vite.config.js corresponding path

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig(
{
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/style.scss',
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

*Note that npm run dev is just for local usage/testing for deployment you should still use npm run build*

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with css and you're getting the same error just with css after
**npm run build**:

> Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css.

In my case i had to change the vite.config.js from

```
laravel({
    input: [
        'resources/scss/app.scss',
        'resources/js/app.js',
    ],
    refresh: true,
})
```

to

```
laravel({
    input: [
        'resources/css/app.css',
        'resources/js/app.js',
    ],
    refresh: true,
})
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run in terminal:

```
npm run dev
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue:

Then start your scss/sass (by whatever way you do it)

```
 sass --watch resources/sass/:resources/css/app.css --style compressed
```

Do you happen to use Vite? if so
Goto your root (vite.config.js) and uncomment

```
'resources/css/app.css',
```

Then go to your sass/scss and make one edit (for example a spacebar click) and then save that.

If you were using Vite before then re add the line in the root

```
 'resources/css/app.css'
```

I hope this works for you. Spamming 'npm run dev' should work but sometimes the old values with strange CSS get pushed to your view and that is why you need to make an edit in your sass/scss file and then save that.

Goodluck!

Comment: Has your issue been resolved? Mind sharing how you did that? running XAMP/MAMP with MySQL and Apache on, and then in project terminal  'php artisan serve' followed by the above, should resolve the issue. But please update.

Answer (score 1):

just don’t add any thing you need to do some edit and it will work ,so
you need to go to app.blade.php in layouts and you will find

```
@vite(["resources/sass/app.scss", "resources/js/app.js"]) on line 18
```

replace it with :

```
@vite(["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"])
```

and your project should be working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
npm update
```

Then open new terminal and run

```
npm run dev
```

Finally open a new terminal and run

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nobody here is trying to explain really what happens.
When you use Laravel + Vite there's a entry point view that you use the vite directive:

your ".blade.php" file:

```php
@vite(['resources/js/app.ts'])
```

- If the Vite server is off (you're not running `npm run dev`), it'll look into the manifest file that is located in `public/build/manifest.json`
- This file contains a map with the build for production files. The key (`resources/js/app.ts`) is pointing to the build files.
- To generate this file you have to run `npm run build`

manifest.json file

```json
{
  "resources/js/app.ts": {
    "css": [
      "assets/app-R6EJiZJt.css"
    ],
    "file": "assets/app-VmbBAHU3.js",
    "isEntry": true,
    "src": "resources/js/app.ts"
  }
}
```

- Now, Laravel Blade's directive `@vite` is retrieving the files from your build folder if you're **NOT** running vite server (which means, you're in production)
- If you're running the vite server (`npm run dev`), the `@vite` directive will get your development files from your `resources` folder or wherever you place it.

#### Conclusion

The `@vite(['resources/js/app.ts'])` directive retrieve the development files if your Vite server is on (`npm run dev`).
If not, it'll look into the `manifest.json` to find the build files.